# Custom CFileDialog Position

Tags: c++, cfiledialog

This is a minor, but annoying issue, and I don't understand why MS have seemingly made it so complicated!

I've created a customised CFileDialog-derived class for opening image files using the 'new' `IFileDialog`, `IFileDialogEvents` and `IFileDialogControlEvents` interfaces. It is all working as intended with my custom controls added (though the lack of control re where these go is a secondary annoying issue!).

The problem is, the dialog will not display centred in my application window, no matter what I try to do. There is also no `OnInitDone` or `OnInitDialog` I can use to reposition it.

Firstly, why is it not centred in the window I specified as the parent / owner?
Secondly, why is it so difficult / impossible to reposition it after the fact?

I don't know how relevant it is but this is how I set it up:

```
COpenImageFileDialog ifd(TRUE, JPG_EXT, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, IMAGE_FILTER, AfxGetMainWnd());
CString sTitle = RESSTR(IDS_IMPORT_IMAGE);
ifd.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = sTitle;
ifd.m_ofn.hwndOwner = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd();
ifd.m_ofn.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
if (ifd.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476169/possible-to-specify-the-start-position-of-an-ifiledialog)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I mean - yes it does, thank you - but it seems ridiculous that we're forced to resort to such hacky tricks.

Comment: Well, you could take the solution you used and create a class derived from `CFileDialog` (maybe call it `CFileDialogEx` or something), that allows the positioning of the dialog (nothing else added, just the position setting).  Then derive `COpenImageFileDialog` from `CFileDialogEx` .

Comment: Yeah I could - but I shouldn't really have to. The new customisation functions for CFileDialog seem half-arsed at best.